# Is there any way to serve PHP on the same port as an Angular 4 CLI site?

Tags: php, angular, angular-cli

I'm developing a webapp (frontend) in Angular 4 which connects to an existing webservice which will later sit in the same domain. I develop the frontend in Visual Studio Code with `npm start` which serves the site at `localhost:4200`. My PHP backend currently runs in XAMPP on port 80.

As no two servers can listen on the same port, is there any way I can serve these two things under the same port? Can I configure the Angular CLI to serve the PHP files as well?

Comment: You can change the `--port` as given to `ng serve` or even include that in your `package.json` for the `start` script. Alternately you could ["proxy" your backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) and change it's port ( or the dev server port ) so that the browser is connecting to the one place but the dev server is forwarding the requests to the backend where it should. Not clear in your question which case is the one that suits. The last sentence seems to suggest the "proxy".

Comment: Note that this is "just for development" and the "dev server" should not in fact be used in production at all, if that is your actual question.

Comment: @ParthChavda The documentation I pointed to disagrees with that statement.

Comment: @NeilLunn I did the proxying and it works like a charm! You could make this an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure Angular CLI to proxy requests to another server.

Assuming all your backend requests are made to `localhost/api/*`: Add a file `proxy.conf.json` to your Angular project with the following contents:

```
{
"/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

and serve the website using `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`. Since you use `npm start`, you will have to change `scripts->start` in `package.json`.

Docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md